# Error : "The system cannot find the file specified". While implementing circular linked-list

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I was solving some linked list question and came across an error "System cannot find the file specified". Let me brief the problem. For inserting element in single linked list I used following commands :

```
     class Node
     {
       public:
       int data;
       Node *next;
     };

     void insertBeg(Node **head_ref, int new_data)
     {
       Node *new_node = new Node();
       new_node->data = new_data;
       new_node->next = *head_ref;
       *head_ref = new_node;
       return;
     }

    int main()
     {
       Node *head = NULL;
       insertBeg(&head,5);
       insertBeg(&head,6);
     }
```

This worked perfectly fine. Then I tried implementing in similar way for circular linked list (For the case when linked list is empty). Below is the code for the same.

```
     class Node 
     {
       public:
       int data;
       Node *next;
     };

     void insertEmpty(Node *last_ref, int new_data)
     {
       Node *new_node = new Node();
       new_node->data = new_data;
       last_ref = new_node;
       last_ref->next = last_ref;
       return;
     }

     int main()
     { 
       Node *last = NULL;
       insertEmpty(last,5);
       return 0;
     }
```

After writing this code the compiler is throwing error  "System cannot find the file specified" . Please help.

Comment: Please post the error message in its entirety.  Paraphrasing often loses vital information that is contained in the message.

Comment: @NathanOliver "The system cannot find the file specified." This was the error shown in the IDE.

Comment: That's all it said?  It didn't say the name of the file it failed to find?

Comment: What does your project structure look like?

Comment: @NathanOliver No it just said "The system cannot find the file specified". I am using sublime text 3 and compiler minGW. For singly linked-list everything worked well but for circular one I am getting this error.

Comment: @AndyG Its not a project. I was just practising  Data Structures. Apart from above code, it has all required header files included.